# Error: PLS-00801: internal error [*** ASSERT at file pdw4.c

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  procedure abc
IS
TYPE abc is table of varchar2(200);
v_nt abc; 

BEGIN

select 'update emp_test set ename=''gaurav'' ' bulk collect into v_nt from emp;

forall i in v_nt.first..v_nt.last
execute immediate v_nt(i);

END; 
/
```

Hi i am creating the above procedure and getting compile time error as shown below:

`Compilation errors for PROCEDURE SCOTT.ABC`

`Error: PLS-00801: internal error [*** ASSERT at file pdw4.c, line  586; Unknown expression Expr = 283.; ABC__SCOTT__P__53497[11, 1]]
Line: 11
Text: execute immediate v_nt(i);`

How can i resolve this ,as i need to do this transaction in bulk.

Comment: The update statement looks very suspicious. It looks like you're trying to update every row in emp_test with the same ename, and you want to run this update once for each row in the emp table. In other words, if there are 10 emp records, you're going to update all 10 records, x 10 times each, all to the same value.

Answer (score 1):

The below should work

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure abc IS
  TYPE abc is table of varchar2(200);
  v_nt abc;
BEGIN
  select 'gaurav' bulk collect into v_nt from emp;
  forall i in v_nt.first .. v_nt.last 
  execute immediate 'update emp_test set ename=:1' using v_nt(i);
END;
      /
```

Although the below also achieves the same result

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure abc IS
 BEGIN
     execute immediate 'update emp_test set ename=''gaurav'' ';
 END;
       /
```

Comment: :that i know  ,but from the above select where i am doing bulk collect ,i am creating an update statement whose set columns and corresponding columns are dynamically populate  ,so this is not possible with the approach by you.Anyways Thanks for the answer +1

Comment: Thanks Gaurav,I tried for another solution but it seams we cannot use collection for table_name or object identifier for update in FORALL since the below e:='update '||a(1)|| 'set '||b(1)||'=' ; forall i in 1..2 execute immediate e||':1' using c(i); END; works but the below code returns the same error e(1):='update '||a(1)|| 'set '||b(1)||'=' ; e(2):='update '||a(2)|| 'set '||b(2)||'=' ; forall i in 1..2 execute immediate e(i)||':1' using c(i);